# Dont take OR condition in if using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am doing a form validation using jquery.But my if condition is not working.Value of contry3 is 'undefined'.
My code is given below

```
var country3=$('.shorttext2').val();
alert(country3);

 if(country3 =='' || country3 =='undefined')
 {
    alert("Please Add Country."); 
    return false;  
 }
```

Anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be

```
if (typeof country3 == "undefined" || country3 =="") {
```

A simple version would be

```
 if(!country3)
 { 
     //not defined, or is empty
 }
```

Comment: Or just check `if (! country3) { }`